# Foundation Equalizer is setting height to inherit?

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get the Equalizer plugin of Foundation to work and the documentation makes it seem pretty simple but I have tried a few things to make it work and still can't figure out why it is not working.

I am calling `foundation.min.js` and activating it as you can see here:
[image: Code Snippet showing activation of Foundation]

Here is my codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByQBYx

As you can see the height is not consistent across the 4 employees.  From what I understand of Equalizer, it is supposed to keep equal height across the 'watched' elements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason this happens is because your divs are stacked.  You need to specify if you want them to remain the same height when stacked.

```
$(document).foundation({
  equalizer : {
    // Specify if Equalizer should make elements equal height once they become stacked.
    equalize_on_stack: true
  }
});
```

Your new codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raWVbO

Comment: This definitely worked but I guess I don't really understand what they mean by the elements are 'stacked'?

Comment: Stacked on top of each other opposed to being in a row horizontally.

Comment: If you want to set this individually instead you can set data-options. For example: <div class="row" data-equalizer data-options="equalize_on_stack: true">

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 6 seems to have simplified the stack option. You can now specify it in the container panel with data-equalize-on-stack="true" like this:

```
<div class="callout" data-equalizer="bar" data-equalize-on-stack="true">
```

The stacking example is under the "Nesting" heading on the [Foundation docs page](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/equalizer.html#nesting).